# Is there a way to change the url paths in CKAN?

Tags: slug, ckan

I want to change *mysite.org/**organization**/someinstitution* to *mysite.org/**institution**/someinstitution*

In [ckan/ckan/config/routing.py](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/master/ckan/config/routing.py#L320) the urls are defined like this:

```
m.connect('organization_read', '/organization/{id}', action='read')
```

Is there a way to change this using an extension or by any other means?, I don't want to modify the master branch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update**: The current best way to implement custom organization types is to use [ckanext-scheming](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-scheming), as described [here](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-scheming#example-schemas---organization). This will automatically register all the appropriate routes for you.

---

It is not as straight-forward as datasets with the `IDatasetForm` interface, but you can change the `/organization` URLs to `/institution` by changing the routing with the `IRoutes` interface.

Here is an example that changes `/organization` to `/publisher`:

https://github.com/IATI/ckanext-iati/blob/b26d2cd518f3991f3c3c954819a582393d9a7e35/ckanext/iati/plugins.py#L69:L103

Comment: Thanks for your answer @amercader. So the only thing I have to do is to bind **ckan.controllers.organization:OrganizationController** to the desired routes?

Comment: Yes, the example shows how to essentially replace all the core routes for the organization controller with custom ones on your extension

Comment: Updated link to above from this time period for those stumbling on this now. https://github.com/IATI/ckanext-iati/blob/b26d2cd518f3991f3c3c954819a582393d9a7e35/ckanext/iati/plugins.py#L69:L103

Comment: Thanks @user3366016, updated the answer with the current recommended approach